# Web services Add service Reference .NET duplicating data contracts

Tags: .net, web-services, service-reference

How to avoid duplicating data contracts when adding service reference to project?
and if there's no way to do this, which classes should I use, duplicated from service proxy or classes which I have referenced to project in usual way?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a service reference you can select the assemblies that contain type that you want to reuse in the [Configure Service Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514724.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use /sharetypes option for the `wsdl` tool

```
wsdl [options] {URL | path}

wsdl /sharetypes http://myfooservice C:\foobar\
```

[WSDL tool on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)